# Selecting element from a DOM using JS

Tags: javascript, html

This selector `doc.getElementsByClassName('value')` needs to target the `td` element which is the next sibling of another `td` which has the text "sign here" so that the image appended after the "abc:".

How can it be done? Thanks

```
let w = window.open();
let doc = w.document;
doc.write(raw_html);
doc.close();
let sigImg = new Image();
sigImg.src = signature;
doc.getElementsByClassName('value').appendChild(sigImg); //wrong selector
```

There are many of `td` and tr element with different class and values.

```
<tr>
  <td class="label">sign here</td>
  <td class="value">abc:</td>
</tr>
```

**edit**
The element index is not known in advance. only that it is after another `td` element which has its text equal to "sign here"

Comment: what is `signature`?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like nodelist. Just access whichever element thru subscript

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList`.  Try `querySelector` which takes a CSS selector and returns the first element that matches.

Comment: @kamoroso94 would the `querySelector` filter out the results by the text inside the td being "sign here"? and if so, how? can you show in an answer? thx

Comment: No you can't use CSS selectors to match elements containing a certain text.  If I were you, I'd put an `id` on the element you need and be done with it.

Comment: @kamoroso94 I don't have that option, the html is not authored locally.

Comment: Are the `class` attributes being `label` and `value` guaranteed/required, or do you want the `nextSibling` of *all* `<td>` elements that have the `textContent==='sign here'` where that nextSibling is also a `<td>`? in other words, with `<td class="label">sign here</td><td class="value">want1</td><td class="foo">sign here</td><td class="bar">want2</td><td class="foo">sign here</td><td class="value">want3</td>`, do you want all the `<td>` elements with `textContent` of: `want1`, `want2`, and `want3`, or only some of them? If not all, which ones do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). Use bracket notation to select element at specific index; e.g., `[0]` to select element at index `0` of returned collection

```
doc.getElementsByClassName('value')[0].appendChild(sigImg);
```

To select element where previous element text contains `"sign here"` you can iterate all elements having `className` `"value"`, check if element `.previousElementSibling` `.textContent` is equal to required text

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">sign here</td>
      <td class="value">abc:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">do not sign here</td>
      <td class="value">def:</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script>
  var sigImg = new Image;
  sigImg.src = "http://lorempixel.com/50/50";
  for (var elem of document.getElementsByClassName("value")) {
    if (elem.previousElementSibling.textContent === "sign here") {
      elem.appendChild(sigImg); break;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Why `new Image;` instead of `new Image();` ?

Comment: @Rayon Either returns same result `function fn() {
  this.name = 123
}

var n = new fn; console.log(n)` _"The [`new operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) creates an instance of a user-defined object type or of one of the built-in object types that has a constructor function."_

Answer (score 0):

Since there will be many `td.label`s and `td.value`s, I'd select every `td.label` and loop trough them comparing their `textContent` to `"sign here"` then grab the next element to work with.

```
var tdLabels = document.querySelectorAll("td.label");
var tdValue = null;
for(var i=0; i<tdLabels.length; i++) {
    var td = tdLabels[i];
    if(td.textContent=="sign here") {
        tdValue = td.parentNode.querySelector("td.value");
        break;
    }
}
// use tdValue somehow, but null if not found
```

This will find the element you're looking for and store a reference to it in `tdValue`.  If such an element doesn't exist, it will be set to `null`.